# Want to Create Pagination on table from Material UI in React Application

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

[image]

I am creating a table with data. Want pagination like this attached image in the footer.
Left-hand side I want the numbers and right-hand side Results per page.

Comment: Have you seen the pagination examples in the [Material UI tables documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/)?

Comment: That pagination is different from mine. I want a square shape on the right side and left side the numbers of page.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have to use the combination of Pagination and Table pagination. And hide the unused panels with the CSS.

```
<div className={classes.root}>
  <Pagination count={10} variant="outlined" shape="rounded" />
  <TablePagination
    component="div"
    count={100}
    page={page}
    onChangePage={handleChangePage}
    rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
    onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
  />
</div>;
```

I have created a sample codesandbox (This is just a workaround) - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-wmm4z?file=/demo.tsx:891-1225

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tejogol mentioned you can use the [Material UI table example](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/) pagination and change it.

You can store the current page number in a state variable and add a different style to the corresponding navigation field. The style seems like a simple border with a small border radius (1-3px).

For the results per page you can use [React spacers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-spacer). Don't forget to update the current page number when changing the results per page.